# watson conversation : Jump to

Tags: watson, watson-conversation

I have a jump-to which "jumps to a response" on a previous node. That previous node was setting some context and responding.

I expect that my jump-to which is configured to "jump to the response only" should only respond and not try to set context again..

I am seeing that the jump is also trying to set the same context on the previous node before responding.Is that the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is the expected behaviour .Jump to Respond will set the context variables as well as give the response without checking the condition